# Gaps between blocks in NiceTabular

Tags: nicematrix, nicetabular

Here's a starting point for my example:

```
\begin{NiceTabular}{c c c c c c}
\hline
x & x & x & x & x & x \\
x & \Block[draw=black]{1-5}{thin} \\
x & x & x & x & \Block[draw=black]{3-2}{tall} \\
x & x & x & x \\
x & x & x & x \\
\hline
\end{NiceTabular}
```

This creates:

[image: I'm too tired right now to think of an image description please forgive me]

I don't want the tall block to be touching the bottom or the thin block. Fixing the first part of that is easy:

```
\begin{NiceTabular}{c c c c c c}
\hline
x & x & x & x & x & x \\
x & \Block[draw=black]{1-5}{thin} \\
x & x & x & x & \Block[draw=black]{3-2}{tall} \\
x & x & x & x \\
x & x & x & x \\
\\[-3mm]
\hline
\end{NiceTabular}
```

[image: I'm too tired right now to think of an image description please forgive me]

But when I try the same for the top margin, this happens:

```
\begin{NiceTabular}{c c c c c c}
\hline
x & x & x & x & x & x \\
x & \Block[draw=black]{1-5}{}  \\
\\[-3mm]
x & x & x & x & \Block[draw=black]{3-2}{tall} \\
x & x & x & x \\
x & x & x & x \\
\\[-3mm]
\hline
\end{NiceTabular}
```

[image: I'm too tired right now to think of an image description please forgive me]

Now the tall block is no longer tall enough to encompass the top row.

How do I create a small gap between the rows/blocks without affecting their size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution which shrinks all the sides of the rectangles.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{c c c c c c}
\hline
x & x & x & x & x & x \\
x & \Block[tikz={offset=0.5pt,draw}]{1-5}{thin} \\
x & x & x & x & \Block[tikz={offset=0.5pt,draw}]{3-2}{tall} \\
x & x & x & x \\
x & x & x & x \\
\\[-4mm]
\hline
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

As usual with `nicematrix`, you need several compilations.

[image: Output of the first code]

---

If you don't want to shrink horizontally, it's always possible to draw whatever you want by using TikZ and the PGF/TikZ nodes created by `nicematrix` under the cells, rows and columns of the tabular.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{c c c c c c}
  \Hline
  x & x & x & x & x & x \\
  x & \Block{1-5}{thin} \\[1mm]
  x & x & x & x & \Block{3-2}{tall} \\
  x & x & x & x \\
  x & x & x & x \\[1mm]
  \Hline
\CodeAfter
  \begin{tikzpicture}  
    \draw (2-|2) rectangle ([yshift=1mm]3-|last) ; 
    \draw (3-|5) rectangle ([yshift=1mm]6-|last) ; 
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the second code]

Comment: For some reason this is giving me an error that says: "Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/offset', to which you passed '0.5pt', and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it." Any idea why?

Comment: I think that you don't have the latest version of `nicematrix`. You should update thoroughly your TeX installation (MiKTeX, TexLives, etc.). If you use Overleaf, you should upload the latest version of the file `nicematrix.sty` in the repertory of your Overleaf project. You can find that file on the SVN server of TeXLive: `www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/nicematrix/nicematrix.sty`

Comment: Now I got it working, thank you! But unfortunately this is not quite what I want. This shrinks the entire rectangle on all sides, which becomes more noticeable when I want to increase the gap size. I want to introduce a gap without changing the rectangle size.

Comment: I have added a second part to my answer.

Comment: This works. Thank you very much!